# Sqlite delete slow in 4GB

Tags: sqlite, database-performance

I have been using fat32 file system. I have a database which has 4 GB size. Database consist of 1 parent table and 1 child table. Parent table has 10 rows and child table has 4000 rows. 1 row of child table has 1 MB size.

When I delete a row in parent table, deletion cascades 1MB-sized child records. (pragma foreign_keys is on) When I try to delete 100 MB data by cascade (1 parent record - 100 child records) it takes too long time (almost 1-10 minute) to complete, and the duration increase/decrease by size of data (100 Mb: 1-10 minute, 300 MB: 3-30 minute,etc).

I tried some pragma commands (synchronous, temp_store, journal_mode) suggested by others posts and i also tried to add index on foreign key, but those does not help solve my problem.(Actually, after adding index on foreign key, 1 MB data deletion became faster/st, but 100 MB data deletion duration did not change) Can you give me please any suggestion to increase deletion performance?

```
CREATE TABLE "ANHXT" (
  "id" integer primary key autoincrement,
  "ANH_AD" text,
  "ANH_DBGMHWID" text,
  "ANH_TYPE" integer,
  "ANH_INDEXNO" int64_t
)

CREATE TABLE "PRCXT" (
  "id" integer primary key autoincrement,
  "ANP_SEGMENTNO" integer not null,
  "ANP_VALUE" blob,
  "ANH_PRC_id" bigint,
  constraint "fk_ANHPRC_ANH_PRC" foreign key ("ANH_PRC_id") references  "ANHXT" ("id") on update cascade on delete cascade deferrable initially deferred
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQC_ANH_TYPE on ANHXT( ANH_TYPE)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQC_ANP_SEGMENTNO_ANAHTARID on PRCXT( ANP_SEGMENTNO,ANH_PRC_id)
CREATE INDEX findex on PRCXT( ANH_PRC_id)
```

Comment: Show the actual table definitions, and any indexes. What are the values of PRAGMA [secure_delete](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete) and [auto_vacuum](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum)?

Comment: There are 2 indexes, the one is to guarantee uniqueness, unique index on the tables, the other is to make the delete operation faster, index for foreign key column. Secure_delete is not active and i don't use auto_vacuum pragma.

Comment: **Show** the actual table definitions, and any indexes.

Comment: I added table definitions and indexes to the message

Comment: What hardware are you using?